# mysql OR will not use index

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I have a mysql Query that will not use an index

- When I use **system.serial = serials.seria**l it will use the
  system.serial index
- When I use **system.serial = LEFT(serials.serial,length(serials.serial)-1)** it will use the
  system.serial index
- When I use **system.serial = serials.serial or system.serial = LEFT(serials.serial,length(serials.serial)-1);**  NO  index is used

Below are the queries with the explain results

Thanks,
Ryan

The Examples only have a few union selects but the actual query has ~7k

```
explain select serials.serial, system.* from 
(SELECT 'S244935X7318894' AS 'serial' 
UNION SELECT 'S244935X6C39166'
UNION SELECT 'S244911X8121539') as serials
left join system on system.serial = serials.serial;

id;select_type;table;type;possible_keys;key;key_len;ref;rows;Extra
1;PRIMARY;<derived2>;ALL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;2;
1;PRIMARY;system;eq_ref;serial_UNIQUE;serial_UNIQUE;182;serials.serial;1;"Using where"
2;DERIVED;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"No tables used"
3;UNION;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"No tables used"
4;UNION;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"No tables used"
NULL;"UNION RESULT";<union2,3,4>;ALL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;



explain select serials.serial, system.* from 
(SELECT 'S244935X7318894' AS 'serial'
UNION SELECT 'S244935X6C39166'
UNION SELECT 'S315185X9703017'
UNION SELECT 'S384860X9A15080A'
UNION SELECT 'S290000X0307210 A2 BLADE') as serials
left join system on  system.serial = LEFT(serials.serial,length(serials.serial)-1) ;

id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,PRIMARY,<derived2>,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,
1,PRIMARY,system,eq_ref,serial_UNIQUE,serial_UNIQUE,182,func,1,"Using where"
2,DERIVED,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
3,UNION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
4,UNION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
5,UNION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
6,UNION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
NULL,"UNION RESULT","<union2,3,4,5,6>",ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,


explain select serials.serial, system.* from 
(SELECT 'S244935X7318894' AS 'serial' 
UNION SELECT 'S244935X6C39166'
UNION SELECT 'S244911X8121539') as serials
left join system on system.serial = serials.serial or system.serial = LEFT(serials.serial,length(serials.serial)-1);


id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,PRIMARY,<derived2>,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,
1,PRIMARY,system,ALL,serial_UNIQUE,NULL,NULL,NULL,190694,"Range checked for each record (index map: 0x4)"
2,DERIVED,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
3,UNION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
4,UNION,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"
NULL,"UNION RESULT","<union2,3,4>",ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
```

Comment: Yep, you shouldn't expect MySQL engine to support `IXOR` operations. It's still a simple engine.

Comment: I always refer to http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or for indexing issues. I haven't looked through it in a while, but reading this through should give you insight into how you may be able to utilize an index for this query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select serials.serial, system.* from 
(SELECT 'S244935X7318894' AS 'serial' 
UNION SELECT 'S244935X6C39166'
UNION SELECT 'S244911X8121539') as serials
left join system on system.serial = serials.serial;
```

Is best done thus:

```
SELECT *
    FROM system
    WHERE serial IN ('S244935X7318894', ...);
```

And have `INDEX(serial)`

In the other cases, `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION DISTINCT` because of avoiding a dedup pass.

(And I agree with the others on `OR` in the last case.)

For the third case (with the `OR`):  Build a temp table, do the `LEFT`, *then* `JOIN system`.  With MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2, that is better done with a non-recursive `CTE`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a great free engine. It has been here long now and it nowadays supports a lot of SQL features.

What you are looking for is an [Index Merge Union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) operation. Though implemented it seems the optimizer doesn't use it often (to be verified as @RickJames states).

In any case, an option to *promote* (never *ensure*) the index usage is to rewrite your query using `UNION ALL`. For example, instead of writing:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1 = 123 OR col1 = 456
```

that probably won't use the index, you can rephrase it as:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1 = 123
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1 = 456
```

Both sections of this query can use a simple "Index Seek" (or "Index Range Scan" in other cases) in MySQL.

Comment: "Index merge union" is implemented, but almost never invoked.  The similar "Index merge intersect" is also rarely used, and almost always not as good as a composite index.  Meanwhile, `UNION ALL` (as noted) or `UNION DISTINCT` (if dups might occur) is a good workaround.

Comment: @RickJames I stand corrected. Never stumbled on the "Index Marge Optimization" (dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html). Now, in terms of why isn't usually invoked, maybe the cost optimizer leaves it out early. Interesting.

Comment: Here's what I _think_.  To do Index Merge Union, one needs to get a bunch of primary keys from the search of one index, then get another bunch from another index.  Combine the two lists, dedup the combined list, then finally fetch the desired rows.  This may involve some number of temp tables (or at least structures malloc'd in RAM).  A lot of work for minimal benefit.

Comment: I _think_ other engines (Oracle, SQL Server, etc) _may_ benefit more from index merge union/intersect:  They don't go through a `PRIMARY KEY`, but instead a "rownum".  That is, their optimizer already is thinking in terms of rownums.  Index merge was added to MySQL after it was at least 10 years old.  Since then I have looked at thousands of EXPLAINs, and almost never seen such.